# How to update nuget packages in many solutions at once

Tags: nuget

I have a repository with a lot of solutions.
Sometimes I need to update one package to a newer version.
It is way to slow opening each solution and updating via visual studio.

What is the best way to update a single package to a newer version for many solutions in the same git repository all at once?

Answer (score 1):

What I did is just find replace the version numbers needed to be updated with the help of sublime. This solution is risky but the only one I have found.

- I updated the references in the solution files and the version
  numbers in the package.config files.

### For example: EntityFramework version 4.3.0 to version 6.0.0

1. Update the solution files
   Find with regex: `<Reference Include="EntityFramework((?s).*?)</Reference>`
   Where: `*.csproj`
   Replace with: `<Reference Include=\"EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0\">\n\t\t<HintPath>$\(SolutionDir\)\\packages\\EntityFramework.6.0.0\\lib\\net45\\EntityFramework.dll<\/HintPath>\n\t<\/Reference>`
2. Update the package files
   Find with regex: `<package id="EntityFramework" version="((?s).*?)" targetFramework="net45" />`
   Where: `packages.config`
   Replace with: `<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />`

Answer (score 1):

NuGet comes with different *frontends*, one being a command line application ([Download](https://www.nuget.org/downloads)) that also allows to update package references. Thomas Ardal provided a [nice PowerShell script](https://thomasardal.com/updating-a-nuget-package-across-multiple-projectssolutions/) that can be used to update packages across multiple solutions:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$packageId
)

Get-ChildItem *.sln -recurse | %{.\\nuget.exe restore $_.fullname}

Get-ChildItem packages.config -Recurse `
  | Where-Object {$_ | Select-String -Pattern $packageId} `
  | %{.\\nuget.exe update -Id $packageId $_.FullName}
```

Please note that this method does not support to control the dependency behavior and will update dependencies to their highest available version.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with NuGet since it relies on Visual Studio as you can see [here](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/05/thoughts-on-installing-and-updating.html).

However, you have an alternative to NuGet, called [Paket](http://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/), which works from the command line.

Working with Paket, you can either manage the packages of your whole repository globally (or per directory) or create a batch to update the package for each solution.

Managing the packages globally, or per directory, means you must have the same version of the packages across all solutions, or across all solutions below the directory paket is managing.